# Problems coloring cells in Latex table

Tags: color, multirow

**Edit:** Apparently, I wasn't very clear on what I wanted. What I wanted to do is alternate the Grey and White colors between the rows. In this case, the first line (the header) should be Grey. With the \multirow, this was not possible without the color covering the text, as you can see with header 4 and header 5.

The \multirow text is covered by the background color. Does someone know why and how can I fix it?
I already tried to add '-' in  `\multirow{-2}{*}{ \textbf{header1}}` as you can see below, but still didn't work for me.

[image: test table]

```
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{p{1.7 cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.9cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{1.55cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.4cm}}
\toprule
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
 \multirow{-2}{*}{ \textbf{header1}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}header2 \end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}header 3.1 \\ \& header 3.2\end{tabular}}} &
   \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}header \\ 4\end{tabular}}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}header \\ 5\end{tabular}}} \\
  \cline{2-7} 
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
 &
  \textbf{A} &
  \textbf{B} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}C\end{tabular}}&
  \textbf{D} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}E \end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}F\\ \end{tabular}}
  &   &  
   \\ \hline
\citet{Jung2014} &
 aaa &
  \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}bbb\\ ccc\end{tabular} &
   &
  eee &
  fff &
  - &
  \_ &
  X \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
  \citet{CAO2020998} &
 aaa &
  \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}bbb\\ ccc\\  ddd\\ kkk\end{tabular} &
   &
  eee &
  fff &
  ttt &
  \_ &
  X \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\caption[Caption for LOF]{Comparison Table of Usage Control Policies \protect\footnotemark}
\label{tab:specification}
\end{table}
```

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example others can just copy and test. We have to add stuff in order to test your sniplet

Comment: You can add `\cellcolor{white}` to  your multirow. This being said I would remove the vertical padding of `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` to delete the upper and lower white strips, which don't look very good.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for your comment. I just added now the packages that I forgot to add before. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Bernard. Thank you for your reply. Could you please elaborate more on how \cellcolor{white} would fix my problem ? Where exactly should I add \cellcolor{white} ?

Comment: Please be so kind and extend you code fragment to complete small document beginning with ˙\|documentclass{...} followed by loading all packages needed to compile it, your code fragment with end by `\end{document}. This document, called MWE (Minimal Working Example) test yourself first and than upload in your question. Please make more clear, what is your problem. Should be text in multirow cell only visible or should be cell background white?

Comment: @Ines: I think it should be `\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\textbf{header1}}`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you are after this:

[image]

(red lines indicate top part of page layout)

With new table package `tabularray` which is based on  LaTeX3, the MWE with your table can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{natbib}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
\begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth,
             colspec = {X[1,l,m]X[1,l,m] X[1,l,m]X[1,l,m] X[1,l,m]X[1,l,m] X[1,l,m]X[1,l,m] X[1,l,m]},
             hlines,   vlines,
             hline{1,5}={1.2pt},
             hline{3}={0.8pt},
             colsep=4pt,
             row{even} = {bg=Gainsboro!60},
             row{1}   = {bg=Gainsboro!60,font=\bfseries},
             row{2}   = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep=1pt,
             }
header1
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{header2}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{{header 3.1 \\ \& header 3.2}}
            &   \multirow{2}{=}{header 4}
                &   \multirow{2}{=}{header 5}   \\
    & A & B & C & D & E & F &   &               \\
\citet{Jung2014}
    &   aaa
        &   {bbb\\ ccc}
            &   &   eee
                    &   fff
                        &   -
                            &   \_
                                &   X           \\
\citet{CAO2020998}
    &   aaa
        &   {bbb\\ ccc\\  ddd\\ kkk}
            &   &   eee
                    &   fff
                        &   ttt &   \_
                                    &   X       \\
\end{tblr}%

\caption[Caption for LOF]{Comparison Table of Usage Control Policies \protect\footnotemark}
\label{tab:specification}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It may be simpler to write `{r=2}` instead of `{r=2,c=1}`.

Comment: @L.J.R., you are right. Corected. I still learn this nice package, and some approach is still rude or are based on extrapolation of showed examples in documentation. So all my answers are also exercises for me ;-).

Comment: @Zarko Thank you very much for your reply. Apparently I wasn't very clear with what I wanted. I wanted to alternate colors Grey and White between rows, so the header would be Grey (including header 1). I can see from your code that I only need to remove `cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{l,white} ` to get the results I need. I will try that for now. Another question as I'm not really familiar with using Tabular array.  In your code, you didn't specify the size of the columns, right? Do you have any specific links for documentation where they describe this package ? Thanks again!

Comment: @Ines, you right, your question is not clear at all. I correct my answer, but similar result gives your code fragment in question. What exactly is your problem? Please, consider all comments below question and edit your question do what you asked for in them.

Comment: @Ines, any news? If edited answer gives what you like to have, you should consider to accept them (by clicking on check mark at the top left side of answer),

Comment: @Zarko, Sorry for the late answer, I was on vacation. Your solution seems exactly what I needed. However, as I'm very unfamiliar with the tabular array environment, I couldn't incorporate your answer in my solution. I have 6 big tables, and it seemed hard for me to incorporate your answer by changing my table environments to a new one. So I'm still looking for a handy solution that suit the tabular environment. Thank you again !

Comment: @Ines, as you wish. However, changing all your tables to `tabularray` is not a big deal. My answer clearly show, how to do this. It take hour or two works to change tables' preambles. All other, as you say `more handy` solution will take more time :-(  I wish you fruitfully waiting to another solution!

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides a command a built-in command `\rowcolors` for coloring rows with alterning colors.

That command has a key `respect-blocks`. With that key, the blocks (created by the command `\Block` will be respected). That means that you will have an alternance of colors for the *logical* rows (rather than for the physical rows of the tabular).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}
   [hvlines-except-borders,cell-space-limits=1mm,color-inside]
   {*{9}{X[l,m]}}
\toprule
\rowcolors{Gainsboro!60}{}[respect-blocks]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{header1}
    &   \Block{1-4}{header2}&&&
        &   \Block{1-2}{header 3.1 \\ \& header 3.2}
            &&   \Block{2-1}{header 4}
                &   \Block{2-1}{header 5}   \\
    & A & B & C & D & E & F &   &               \\
?
    &   aaa
        &   \Block{}{bbb\\ ccc}
            &   &   eee
                    &   fff
                        &   -
                            &   \_
                                &   X           \\
?
    &   aaa
        &   \Block{}{bbb\\ ccc\\  ddd\\ kkk}
            &   &   eee
                    &   fff
                        &   ttt &   \_
                                    &   X       \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\caption[Caption for LOF]{Comparison Table of Usage Control Policies \protect\footnotemark}
\label{tab:specification}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]